# MS Access 2013 filter report from multiple tables, using unbound form

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a database of students and exam results, with several tables.

Users need to generate reports on a subset of students: only some years, dates, etc.

I already have a pretty report of the whole joined database. I have a query that returns the right records based on parameters it asks for at run time. I have a 'start page' form with unbound fields for entering the parameters. None of these 3 are connected up to each other...

This sounds basic and hopefully it is but I'm stuck... I'm OK with VBA, SQL or whatever anyone would like to suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can you not use the query to build the report? It is often good to have a small form to supply all the parameters for a query or report.

Comment: Thanks...I'm trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the criteria section (or the WHERE clause if you are using SQL) you would add the filter in this format:

**=[Forms]![YourFormName]![YourUnboundField].[Text]**

One other option is to use the Expression Builder and navigate to your form containing the unbound fields and select the expression value you want - in this example I chose [Text].

One thing to note, your form containing the fields will need to remain open when you run the report.

Comment: I've been trying that...not quite working for me but at least it means I'm on the right track. Thanks. I'll post any specific problems when I get them.

Comment: .Text property is only available when the control has focus. Either do not use a property (best) or use value.